# Get value of active card

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC page dynamically generating a card element for each item retrieved from a database - each card has a button on it and I'm trying to set some values from the card that's been clicked on to populate a different element.

Card code:

```
<div class="uk-grid">

    @foreach (var entry in Model.Items)
    {
        <div>
                <div class="uk-card uk-card-hover uk-card-body">
                    @if (entry.new_Flag == 1)
            {
                        <span class="uk-label-newitem" style="display: normal;">New Item</span>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <span class="uk-label-newitem" style="display: none;">New Item</span>
                    }
                    @if (entry.stage1_flag == 1)
            {
                        <span class="uk-label-s1" style="display: normal;">Awaiting Stage 1 Sign Off</span>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <span class="uk-label-s1" style="display: none;">Awaiting Stage 1 Sign Off</span>
                    }

                    @if (entry.stage2_flag == 1)
            {
                        <span class="uk-label-s2" style="display: normal;">Awaiting Stage 2 Sign Off</span>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <span class="uk-label-s2" style="display: none;">Awaiting Stage 2 Sign Off</span>
                    }

                    @if (entry.live_flag == 1)
            {
                        <span class="uk-label-live" style="display: normal;">Item Live</span>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <span class="uk-label-live" style="display: none;">Item Live</span>
                    }
                    <h3 class="uk-card-title" id="uk-card-title"><b>@entry.kpi_Name</b></h3>
                    <p>Info here</p>
                    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default" type="button" id="btndetails" data-interaction="@entry.kpi_pk" uk-toggle="target: #offcanvas-overlay">Details</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('#btndetails').on('click', function () {
        //var id = $('#uk-card-title').text();
        //var id = $(this).find('#uk-card-title').text();

        var id = $(this).closest("uk-card-title").text();

        alert(id);
```

I have an off-canvas element that slides in to display more info from the card but those details need to be set from this button click action and taken from the card.
At the moment the alert is triggered when the first card is clicked but none of the others

Comment: if you are looking for previous h3 use `.prev().prev()` and not `closest()` , `closest()` will look for parent not sibling

Comment: You mean like this? `var $item = $(this).prev("uk-card-title").text();`

Comment: `$(this).prev().prev().text();` like this but this is not that clean if you will change the mark up

Comment: OK that works but again only for the first card created... any subsequent cards don't trigger the alert and only open the side bar

Comment: you are using ID. if you have other I assume you have same ID. ID should be unique. Use class instead then use `this` to refer to clicked element.

Comment: Do you mean the button ID?

Comment: yes.. because ID should be unique on context use `class` instead

Comment: OK think I'm heading in the right direction but this now doesn't trigger the alert... `$('.uk-button uk-button-default').click(function () {
            var item = $(this).prev().prev("uk-card-title").text();
            alert(item);
        });`

Comment: remove this `"uk-card-title"` in second prev.. if you want to add the class you need to add `.`

Comment: Perfect - got it all working now! Thanks

Comment: glad to help mate happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @guradio fixed it by using:

```
    $(".uk-button").on('click', function () {
        var $item = $(this).prev().prev().text();
        alert($item);
    });
```